# Nodejs + Knex + Postgres: Unhandled rejection Error: Pool is destroyed

Tags: node.js, postgresql, bookshelf.js, knex.js

My team and I use knex and postgres to handle all our database work. From time to time, we'll get the following error:

`Knex:Error Pool2 - error: too many connections for role "<rolename>"`

Followed by this error with every request:

```
 app[web.2]: Unhandled rejection Error: Pool is destroyed
 app[web.2]:     at Pool.acquire (/app/node_modules/knex/node_modules/pool2/lib/pool.js:163:12)
 app[web.2]:     at /app/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:204:19
 app[web.2]:     at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
 app[web.2]:     at Promise._resolveFromResolver (/app/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:480:31)
 app[web.2]:     at new Promise (/app/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:70:37)
 app[web.2]:     at Client.acquireConnection (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:200:12)
 app[web.2]:     at /app/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:138:49
 app[web.2]:     at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
 app[web.2]:     at Function.Promise.attempt.Promise.try (/app/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/method.js:31:24)
 app[web.2]:     at Runner.ensureConnection (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:137:26)
 app[web.2]:     at Runner.run (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:30:31)
 app[web.2]:     at QueryBuilder.Target.then (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/interface.js:27:43)
 app[web.2]:     at QueryBuilder.tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bookshelf/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
 app[web.2]:     at doThenable (/app/node_modules/bookshelf/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/thenables.js:52:38)
 app[web.2]:     at tryConvertToPromise (/app/node_modules/bookshelf/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/thenables.js:30:20)
 app[web.2]:     at Promise._resolveCallback (/app/node_modules/bookshelf/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:442:24)
 app[web.2]:     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/app/node_modules/bookshelf/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:515:17)
 app[web.2]:     at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/app/node_modules/bookshelf/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:581:18)
 app[web.2]:     at Promise._settlePromises (/app/node_modules/bookshelf/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:697:14)
 app[web.2]:     at Async._drainQueue (/app/node_modules/bookshelf/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:123:16)
 app[web.2]:     at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bookshelf/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:133:10)
 app[web.2]:     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/app/node_modules/bookshelf/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)
 app[web.2]:     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:368:17)
```

Our pool settings are:

```
pool: {
  min: 2,
  max: 10
}
```

We've tried setting it to `min:0` but that hasnt helped. At least locally.

**Question 1** : Can we track the number of active connections and make sure there arent any "orphaned" connections? If so, how?

**Question 2** : Is the `Pool is destroyed` error occurring because we are unable to make a connection with the DB, and therefore Knex assumes the pool doesnt exits?

**Question 3** : Can we somehow set the API to go into a "standby mode" when it cannot make a connection and wait for an open one to occur?

**Question 4** : Is a max setting of 10 too low for any sort of production application? We're still in beta, but we're going to have a massive increase in traffic soon.

#### Update:

We even increased our `pool.max` to 15 and we're still having this issue.

Comment: The error message is coming from the postgresql server, check its configuration. But yeah, you may be having some connection leak on your application side.

Comment: Did you have any luck resolving this issue? Running into the same error.

Comment: Not really. It was only happening on our Heroku dev account which is just a hobby tier. It doesnt happen on our paid prod account

Answer (score -2):

The issue is with DB connection. You can check your DB related configuration such as userName and password.

Comment: You can send this answer as a comment.